# How to integrate Facebook account, friend list into Pinax Django project?

Tags: django, facebook, integration, pinax

I wanna run a project based on Pinax social project.
And I want to let users login with facebook account, not only use the facebook information to sign up at my site, but also **grab the existing friend list from facebook.**
So users dont need to add friends again, and they can see the facebook friends who also signed up at my site.

Normal sign up procedure would be retained for users who dont have facebook account.
And then they must add friends as usual.

Is there any django-app(s) suitable for my goal?
And is there any tricky or magical things for integration into Pinax?
It's some kind of more complex scenario, or should I simplify something?

Any suggestion would help...
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is [django-facebook](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook) or [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth)

Answer (score 0):

I would do that with [Django Social Auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) to take care of the authentication part and then I would add [Django Social Friends Finder](https://github.com/laplacesdemon/django-social-friends-finder) as an add on to Django Social Auth to get a user's list of social friends in common with the users already signed up on your site.
The fact that you are using Pinax should make no difference.